# Where do I change the screensaver options in 13.04?

Tags: screen, lock-screen, screensaver

I'm having a problem with the screen blanking every 10 minutes. I've tried every fix suggested on ask ubuntu but nothing has worked.

I typed $xset -q

$ xset -q

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  195    repeat rate:  47
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x22    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

What has suprised me is that the screen saver still has options set, yet I cannot find any screen saver options? Where do I find the screen saver options?

Comment: the latest version doesn't come with screensavers, but if you want them, try XScreensaver.

Comment: I think I'll just install 13.10 and hope this bug does away

Comment: it's not a bug, just Ubuntu think you don't need screensavers. If you want them, do try the program. :-)

Comment: It's a bug if I have disabled all screen blanking and there isn't a screensaver but I still get screen blanking and xset tells me I have a screen saver setting that tells me that I prefer screen blanking. Wierdly, have upgraded to 13.10 and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 1):

Change settings for the time it takes for the screen to blank out in:

System Settings --> Brightness & Lock --> Turn screen off when active for: <5 minutes>